# Out of bounds exception - 2D array maze

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, maze

I am new here and new to coding in general! It's exciting to learn but tedious as ever. I am writing a program where a char needs to solve a maze. I am no where near finished here, but for some reason I am getting an out of bounds exception on any array greater than 3 in length. I have no idea why. There are test cases and you can see the small mazes print successfully, however, when I try a bigger maze I get an out of bounds exception.

Any advice?

```
import java.awt.Point;


public class Maze 
{
    final char WALL = 'x';
    final char BOT = 'r';
    final char FREE = ' ';

    private String[] maze;
    private Point position;
    private boolean[][] mazeWalls;

    public Maze(String[] strings) // constructor to create maze from main as a 2D array
    {
        maze = strings;
        mazeWalls = new boolean[strings[0].length()][strings.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < mazeWalls.length; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < mazeWalls[0].length; j++)
                {
                    if (strings[i].charAt(j) == WALL) // this is where it shows the out of bounds error on m[3] or m[4]
                        mazeWalls[j][i] = true;

                    else if (strings[i].charAt(j) == BOT)
                    {
                        position = new Point(i, j);
                    }
                }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Maze m;
        /*m = new Maze(new String[] {
                "xxx",
                "xrx",
                "xxx"});
        m = new Maze(new String[] {
                "xxx",
                "xrx",
                "x x"});
        m = new Maze(new String[] {
                "xxx",
                "xr      ",
                "xxx",});*/
        m = new Maze(new String[] {
                "xxxxx",
                "xr  x",
                "x   x",
                "x    ",
                "x   x",
                "x   x",
                "xxxxx"});
        /*m = new Maze(new String[] {
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xr  r                 x                     x",
        "x                    x                     x",
        "x   x                x                      ",
        "x   x                x                     x",
        "x   x                x                     x",
        "x   x                x                     x",
        "x   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx             x",
        "x   x                                      x",
        "x   x                                      x",
        "x   x                                      x",
        "x   x                                      x",
        "x   x                                      x",
        "x   x                                      x",
        "x   x                                      x",
        "x   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "x   x                                      x",
        "x   x                                      x",
        "x   x                                      x",
        "x                                          x",
        "x                                          x",
        "x                                          x",
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"});*/
                Robot r = new RandomBot();
            //  Robot r = new RightHandBot();

                int c = 0;
                System.out.println(m);
                while (!m.isRobotOnEdge())
                {
                    c++;
                    Point move = r.getMove(m);
                    m.moveTo(move);
                    System.out.println("Step Count: " + c);
                    System.out.println(m);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                }   
    }

    public void moveTo(Point p) 
    {
        /*for (int i = 0; i < mazeWalls.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < mazeWalls[0].length; j++)
            {
                if (maze[i].charAt(j) == BOT)
                    position = p;
            }*/
    }

    public Point getPoint()
    {
        return (Point)position.clone();
    }

    public boolean wallObject(Point p)
    {
        return wallHere(position.x, position.y);
    }

    public boolean wallHere(int x, int y)
    {
        return x < 0 || x >= mazeWalls.length || y < 0 || y >= mazeWalls[0].length || mazeWalls[x][y];
    }

    public boolean isRobotOnEdge() 
    {
                if (position.x == mazeWalls.length - 1 || position.y == mazeWalls[0].length - 1 || position.x == 0 || position.y == 0)
                    return true;
        return false;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String s = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < mazeWalls.length; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < mazeWalls[0].length; i++)
                {
                    if (i == position.x && j == position.y)
                        s += BOT;
                    else if (mazeWalls[i][j] == true)
                        s += WALL;
                    else
                        s += FREE;
                }
             s += "\n";
            }

        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you point us to the line where you're getting an index out of bounds exception? Not the number, but the line contents for reference. One thing you might want to consider is SSCCE: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are translating a 1D `String` array to a 2D `boolean` array but the size of the target array is the wrong way round. The number of rows & columns are different so it matters how the 2D array is sized. Look at this:

```
                            ROWS                COLUMNS
mazeWalls = new boolean[strings[0].length()][strings.length];
```

it should be

```
mazeWalls = new boolean[strings.length][strings[0].length()];
```

Also unless, you are attempting to transpose the values, this line

```
mazeWalls[j][i] = true;
```

should be

```
mazeWalls[i][j] = true;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually just figured it out on my own. The problem was that my instructor told me to switch them around, confusing the hell out of me. Anyways, thanks a lot! Now that I'm past that I can try and figure out how to get this'r' char to move around the maze!

Comment: Treat the 1D `String` array like a 2D array. Use array index and `String#charAt` as the `i` & `j` indexes/co-ords. Track the current these row & column coords adding checking for walls. Good Luck!